# Is there any json schema like a excel table in Api Blueprint MSON?

Tags: json, jsonschema, apiblueprint, mson, aglio

Is there any json schema like a excel table in Api Blueprint MSON ?

I am designing some api between several clients.
So I need api documentation tool that can present as easy readable format.
I search these 3 solution. (Swagger, RAML, Api Blueprint).
I decide Api Blueprint because it can present more rich form with markdown.
Almost every functions in Api Blueprint satisfied me.
But the json schema format is so complicate and hard to read.
I want my result html like the below finally.
(I used aglio as a Api Blueprint html renderer.)

[image]

this is my apib source code

```
FORMAT: 1A



# GET /MyApi

- Request
    - Attributes
        - name : hhd (string, required) - this is person name
        - age : 37 (number, optional) - this is person age
        - pets (array)
            - (object)
                - name : tom (string, optional) - this is pet's name
                - type : dog (string, required) - this is pet's type
            - (object)
                - name : jane
                - type : cat


- Response 200
    - Attributes
        - status : ok (string, required)
        - id : 1000 (number, required)
        - name : hhd (string, required) - this is person name
        - age : 37 (number, optional) - this is person age
        - pets : (array)
            - (object)
                - id : 10001 (number, required)
                - name : tom (string, optional) - this is pet's name
                - type : dog (string, required) - this is pet's type
            - (object)
                - id : 10002
                - name : jane
                - type : cat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported in Aglio. You could write a custom theme layout or theme engine to support this.